# Getting strange java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error

Tags: java, methods

I have an interface called Namable

```
public interface Namable { public String getName(); public void setName(String name); };
```

Several classes will implement this.

When I make code like this:

`Namable foo = new X(); foo.getName();`

(X is an implementing class)

I get the error:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Namable.getName()Ljava/lang/String;`

This is very strange to me and I'm wondering why this is happening, any thoughts?

Compilable example:

Namable class:

```
public interface Namable 
  {
    public String getName();
  }
```

Extending class X:

```
public class X extends java.util.ArrayList implements Namable 
{
  private String name;
  public X() 
  {
    this.name = "bar";
  }
  public String getName() 
  {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Testing class:

```
public class Test 
{
  public static void main() 
  {
    Namable foo = new X();
    foo.getName();
  }
}
```

After running this, I get the same error.  I am using BlueJ

Comment: Are you missing a `new` in `Namable foo = X()` or is `X` a static factory method?  Are you doing anything exotic with proxy classes?  Are you using an exotic framework, like a DI framework or test stubbing framework that uses proxy classes?

Comment: Please provide more code (and correct code) for this issue. I think you're being too brief to accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Ok, There is a "new" in the code and X is just a class (X also happens to extend ArrayList, could this be part of it?). I am not doing anything fancy... In fact, I took the problem out of context and tried to debug it as shown above and its still giving the same error.

Comment: The problem goes away once I change "Namable foo" to "X foo".  But its not realistic with my project architecture to do this since many classes implement Namable I need a way to generalize all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have run an example with the classes you have given here and it works as expected once the main method is changed to:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

However, as you are using BlueJ this may not be a problem (I remember BlueJ using a special mechanism to run classes).

Do you have another class `Nameable` in your classpath? Check the package import and make sure it is the interface you have defined. It appears the error is with your environment and not with the code.

Comment: This seemed to do the trick. The code had nothing to do with it and once i tweaked these the problem went away. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to call

```
foo.getName()
```

not

```
X.getName()
```

You are trying to call a class (static) method that doesn't exist.

And it should be `Namable foo = new X();` - your example code shouldn't even compile as shown.

Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) ?

**Updated following corrections and SSCCE:** Just a wild guess now, but does BlueJ define a Namable already, or do you have a Namable in another package that might be imported instead? What happens if you rename Namable to Namable2 throughout, in the example above?

Comment: Oh dear.. I'm sorry that was a typo I am calling the method by its instance name

Answer (score 0):

As stated by DNA your post would be better with a SSCCE

My guess would be that maybe you could have missed a "`static`" keyword in main function

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

not

```
public void main(String args[])
```

Could be something a classpath problem too... Or a file name and class mismatch. Or something else.

Comment: If the problem is a classpath or name mismatch issue what should I do to fix it. I've never encountered something like this

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code snippet, the error shown is

> Error: Main method not found in class Test, please define the main
>   method as:    public static void main(String[] args)

Change your `main` method to

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

I am not getting

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Namable.getName()Ljava/lang/String;

with your given code snippet.

Comment: I'm starting to believe this is a problem with BlueJ... I created a completely new project to test my code snippet and got the same error